# what is use of router and model in loopback

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

hello guys i m new to loopback so can anyone help me with this basic. i had created a some code but don't know how this flow (from route  to model)
here is route.js code  for login

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = function(app) {
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('login');
});
 app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
 //from here i should go to login model
 });
};
```

here is my login.ejs

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
<input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
</form>
```

now my question is that how i can use login model  from  route.js (url is like "login") i know i can use this type as describe below in route.js but i want that first it go to  router and from then i go to login model more description  eg it go through "/login" route from there  it go to login model where i want to add insert login after that if it response success then it go to "/home" else it go to "/"

```
"var User = app.models.user;"
```

i what something like this in user.js (model)

```
module.exports = function(User) {
//here i want to accept login form method and insert it into dataabase
};
```

or this is not possible or it is incorrect way i don't know much so please help
what is different between if i use business login in router and model i m new so please help.

Answer (score 0):

First go to the loopBack documentation and read it carefully how to create models and its control flow , surely you will get clear picture

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Project-layout-reference.html

Comment: @mohammadreaheem i readed all this thing this is not i want i want just route and logic in seprate section